# Are Apsaras promiscuous women for the enjoyment of the inhabitants of heaven?

Tags: apsaras

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31867/why-does-the-apsara-menaka-keep-abandoning-her-children/31875#31875) cites a verse from the Devi Bhagavatam:

> Then those **prostitutes of the Devas**, dressed with their heavenly
>   ornaments and the heavenly flowers, appeared before the Munis and
>   bowed down their heads on the ground.

The part in bold is referring to the [Apsaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsara), otherwise known as celestial nymphs. Their job is to basically go around and have sex with everyone who has been rewarded with heaven.

Here is another verse from the Mahabharata:

> "We Apsaras are free and unconfined in our choice. It behooves you
>   not, therefore, to esteem me as your superior. The sons and grandsons
>   of Puru's race, that have come here in consequence of ascetic merit do
>   all sport with us, without incurring any sin. We have no husband, no
>   sons, indeed, no relations."

Are there any other scriptural verses that talk about the sexual services provided by the Apsaras?

Comment: Apsaras != celestial nymphs, please back it up with scriptural reference. I find the question to be invalid. The "quote" from mahabarata with read with a different understanding of Apsaras has a different meaning altogether

Comment: @Akhil What meaning is that? Can you explain your understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any other scriptural verses that talk about the sexual
>   services provided by the Apsaras?

Although the Apsaras basically do that all the time (as that is their job) but scriptures are not the correct texts (sources) where we can find out about their exploits. So, basically the scriptures will not go into the details.

Scriptures are Sattvik and they deal with Dharma. And, the books that contain the sexual exploits of the Apsaras can not be considered as Sattvik.

This is explained in the following verses:

> Verily out of the five organs of perception the organ of hearing and
>   the organ of sight are benefitting, for the knowledge of things arises
>   from hearing and the heart is pleased by seeing. Therefore the Pundits
>   divide in three classes, the objects of hearing, as :-- (1) Sâttvik,
>   (2) Râjasik and (3) Tâmasik. **The Vedas and other S’âstras are
>   Sâttvik;** the **literature Sahitya is the Râjasik** and war news and
>   finding fault with others is Tâmasik. The wise persons again
>   sub-divide the Sâttvik in three subclasses :-- good, middling and
>   worst. That which gives Moksa is good or excellent; that which gives
>   Heavens is middling and that which gives this worldly pleasure is
>   worst. In the same way, the literature Sahitya is of three kinds :--
>   That which describes the people to live with their legitimate wives is
>   the best; **which describes about prostitutes is the middling;** and
>   that which makes people live with other's wives is the worst.
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam 1.6**

So, we can expect Sahityas to contain those sort of stuffs and not the scriptures. Even the Sattvik-natured Sahitya will not describe the Apasara-like activities, the Rajasik-natured Sahitya will.

Comment: What are you trying to say? I didn't understand

Comment: My answer says scriptures are not the correct place to look into for finding Apasara's exploits.. there are different natured erotic literatures which may contain such info .. @NaveenKick

Comment: If you know of any Sahitya scriptures that talk about the sexual services provided by the Apsaras, can you cite them?

Comment: But even the Itihasas like the Mahabharata talk about their exploits, as in the case of Menaka and my quotation in the OP.

Comment: I don't know abt any such erotic literature .. but must be there or must hv been there .. even some Smritis say not to read such "asat Shastras" probably referring to such books ..  I thought u want to know which scriptures contain the details of their exploits .. that their nature is such is evident from many passages in many scriptures including the one already quoted in the Q from Mahabharat @Ikshvaku

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, Apsaras are promiscuous women for the enjoyment of the inhabitants of heaven, in other words, **prostitutes**.

Rickross (Most upvoted answer) quoted Devi Bhagavatam 1.6 to say that the Apsara's sexual exploitation isn't in Sattvik, but how can we trust Devi Bhagavatam as reliable in defining Sattvik when **Devi Bhagavatam itself calls Apsaras prostitutes:**

**Devi Bhagavatam Book 4. [Chapter 6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57170.html). Verse 28-29:**

> Eight thousand and five hundred Apsarâs and long multitudes of the hosts of Cupid, the Munis saw and were surprised. **Then those
> prostitutes of the Devas**, dressed with their heavenly ornaments and
> the heavenly flowers, appeared before the Munis and bowed down their
> heads on the ground.

**Again in Verse 58:**

> If you like to go to Heaven, be pleased to know that there is no Superior Heaven to Gandhamâdan (the mountain like intoxicating
> happiness of the senses). **Dost thou enjoy the highest bliss, the
> pleasant sexual intercourse with us, the heavenly damsels in this very
> beautiful and lovely place.**

**Devi Bhagavatam Book 9. [Chapter 1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57314.html). Within Verses 96-143:**

> Those women that are sprung from Sattva Guna are all very good-natured and chaste; those that are sprung from Rajo Guna are middling
> and very much attached to worldly enjoyments and do their selfish ends
> and those that are sprung from Tamo Guna are recognised as worst and
> belonging to the unknown families. They are very scurrilous, cheats,
> ruining their families, fond of their own free ways, quarrelsome and
> no seconds are found equal to them. **Such women become prostitutes in
> this world and Apsarâs in the Heavens.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi! I have edit-formatted your answer for better readability. If you don't like my edit, please feel free to roll it back. :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to the site, so I still have a bit to learn about formatting.