# How do Apsaras look? What are their physical characteristics and physical appearance?

Tags: apsaras

Apsaras are said to be so beautiful that they enchant and mesmerize even Rishis.

How do Apsaras look? What are their physical characteristics and physical appearance?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31882/are-apsaras-promiscuous-women-for-the-enjoyment-of-the-inhabitants-of-heaven?rq=1 has an answer

Comment: @SK I want a more elaborate description. All that question says is: "dressed with their heavenly ornaments and the heavenly flowers"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well from what we have read and heard Apsaras are mostly used to entice/lure others mainly for entertainment or to accomplish some hidden motives. From what I have read Apsaras are very beautiful with big sharp eyes, slender body, long hair, big hips and they walk in a manner so as to seduce others.

**[ŚB 8.8.7](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/8/7/)** says:

> Next there appeared the Apsarās [who are used as prostitutes on the
>   heavenly planets]. They were fully decorated with golden ornaments and
>   lockets and were dressed in fine and attractive clothing. The Apsarās
>   move very slowly in an attractive style that bewilders the inhabitants
>   of the heavenly planets.

**[The Mahabharata, Book 3: Vana Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03046.htm)**

> And when the twilight had deepened and the moon was up, that **Apsara of
>   high hips** sent out for the mansions of Arjuna.

**[The Mahabharata, Book 12: Santi Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c024.htm)**

> While thus engaged, the illustrious Rishi, O king, beheld the **Apsara
>   Ghritachi**, who, in consequence of her energy, **was then possessed
>   of great beauty**.

Also as has been described [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/ii.htm):

> In grace and beauty grew the maid, as if Lakshmi's own self had taken
>   woman's form. And when swift years her gracious youth made ripe,
>   **Like to an image of dark gold she seemed Gleaming, with waist so fine, and breasts so deep, And limbs so rounded. When she moved, all
>   eyes Gazed after her, as though an Apsara Had lighted out of Swarga.**
>   Not one dared, Of all the noblest lords, to ask for wife That miracle,
>   with eyes purple and soft As lotus-petals, that pure perfect maid,
>   Whose face shed heavenly light where she did go.