# Can anyone give me the reference of this? (Women being arranged according to number of men she is "addicted" to)

Tags: women, sex

Can anyone give me reference where this thing is written? (I found this on Twitter.)

[image]

Comment: Please search before posting a Q .. it might have been answered already. In this case its a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which scripture say any woman having intercourse with 5 different men is a prostitute?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23108/which-scripture-say-any-woman-having-intercourse-with-5-different-men-is-a-prost)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not a forum for comments on social media postings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is  found in the [**Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa, Canto 9, Chapter 35, Verses 1-7**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57348.html):

> Dharmarājan said:- O Chaste One! Without serving the Gods, the Karma ties can never be severed. The pure acts are the seeds of purities and the impure acts lead to impure seeds. If any Brāhmaṇa goes to any unchaste woman and eats her food, he will have to go ultimately to the Kālasūtra hell. There he lives for one hundred years when ultimately he gets a human birth when he passes his times as a diseased man and ultimately he gets purified. **Those women who are addicted to their (one) husbands only are called Pativratās. Those addicted to two persons are named Kulaṭās; to three, are called Dharṣiṇīs; to four, called Puṃścalīs; to five, six persons, called Veśyās; to seven, eight, nine persons are called Puṅgīs; and to more than these, are called Mahāveśyās. The Mahāveśyās are unfit to be touched by all the classes.**