# When were women allowed to have multiple husbands without sin?

Tags: dharma, women, sex

When were women allowed to have multiple husbands without sin?

According to this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19254/11726), the Rishis permitted this practice at one point in history:

> King Pandu well-acquainted with all rules of morality, replied ... But I shall now tell thee about the practices of old indicated by illustrious Rishis, fully acquainted with every rule of morality... women formerly were not immured within houses and dependent on husbands and other relatives. They used to go about freely, enjoying themselves as best as they liked ... they did not then adhere to their husbands faithfully, and yet, O handsome one, they were not regarded sinful

During what time period was this allowed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132732/discussion-on-question-by-ikshvaku-when-were-women-allowed-to-have-multiple-husb).