# Did the Society during the time of Mahabharata consider a common wife "polyandry" or "fraternal polyandry" condemned act?

Tags: mahabharata

During the time of Mahabharata, did the society consider polyandry or fraternal polyandry a condemned or shameful act?

Comment: After your edit, it now seems like a duplicate of [Was Polyandry allowed prior to Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/was-polyandry-allowed-prior-to-mahabharata). Your original question was fine. There was no reason to edit it. As answers to  [Was Polyandry allowed prior to Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/was-polyandry-allowed-prior-to-mahabharata) prove, dharma indeed changes with time.

Comment: Dharma DOES change over time. This is why there is a smriti for every yuga.

Comment: @sv. I rollbacked to the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A women should marry only a single person according to [Mahabharat.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01124.htm)

> They used to go about freely, enjoying themselves as best as they liked ... they did not then adhere to their husbands faithfully, and yet, O handsome one, they were not regarded sinful, ... **The present practice, however (of women's being confined to one husband for life)** hath been established but lately. Women transgressing the limits assigned by the Rishi became guilty of slaying the embryo.

Karna [said](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02067.htm) during Vastraharan to Vikarna.

> O son of the Kuru race, **the gods had ordained only one husband for one women.** This Draupadi however hath many husbands. Therefore, certain it is that she is an unchaste women.

Comment: How about Kalki? He will get 2 wives.

Comment: @Wikash_ I am talking about women.