# Who is a Pativrata Stree?

Tags: scripture, puranas, marriage, sati, pativrata

If a woman marry 2 men then would she be worthy for having title of Pativrata stree or SATI? I want to know the titles of women given by their numbers of husbands in Hinduism. Like if 1 husband then she is Pativrata, 5 husband=Punschali...like this. And I have a great confusion because I have seen people talking about women having 4 husbands in Hinduism, is it OK to have 4 husbands for a Hindu Woman.Is it correct? Pativratas are not meant to have relation with Par-purush but if my wife marry other purush then he shall not be a par purush for my wife anymore. Then will she be a pativrata? Please give me shastra reference with shlokas regarding of my confusion. Does pativrata stree want more than one husband? If not then why draupadi is still known as Pativrata/Sati today?

Comment: ***women having 4 husbands in Hinduism...*** Any example from mythology?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did the Society during the time of Mahabharata consider a common wife "polyandry" or "fraternal polyandry" condemned act?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/39946/did-the-society-during-the-time-of-mahabharata-consider-a-common-wife-polyandry)

Comment: Draupadī, has been faithful and loyal to her husbands alone, and never had thought of romantic love, or lust towards any other man. She is pure in her conduct and thus she is revered as a satī. Any wife can be a satī, not only Draupadī. Even Tārā and Mandodarī were satīs

Comment: For a married women to be a pativratā, it's not exactly like she should have 2 or 4 husbands. She can have even a single husband, and she can be pativrata. Sāvitrī, Anasūyā, Arundhatī, Sitā, Ahalyā etc, are all pativratā satīs, who have just 1 husband. Also, Draupadī married the five brothers together, it wasn't like she married them separately, and without the other's knowledge. Also, Pāñcālī is the name of Draupadī, not because of her marriage to the Pāṇḍavas, but because she is the princess of the kingdom of Pāñcāla.