# Who started the traditon of women being first wedded to three devtas before being wedded to the husband?

Tags: vedas, marriage, polyandry

In [Vedic Vivah (Vedic Wedding)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8coURgp5LtA) , the girl  is first wedded to three devtas (Chandra Dev, Gandharva Vishwashu and Agni Dev) then in the last she is wedded to the husband .

[Is it true](https://www.youngisthan.in/hindi/every-husband-fourth-husband-70596/) that this tradition was started by [Rishi SwetaKetu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/was-polyandry-allowed-prior-to-mahabharata) ?

Answer (score 7):

We find mentions of a maiden being "enjoyed" by Moon, Gandharva and Agni in the scriptures themselves. So, the tradition can be a scriptural one and not started by any individual.

> Having given away [a maiden], sanctified with HomaMantrams, a person
> attains the fruits of hundreds of Jyotistoma-Sacrifice. (63)
>
> Having given away a maiden-daughter, decorated with ornaments, clothes
> and seats a father attains to the celestial region and is adored of
> the Suras (celestials) . (64)
>
> **The Moon enjoys a maiden when hairs grow on her person ; seeing the menstrual blood the Gandharvas [enjoy her] ; and seeing her rising
> breasts, the Fire. (65)**
>
> [A maiden] eight years [old] becomes a Gouri ; one of nine years a
> Rohini; and of ten years, a Kanya (maiden) ; and after that a
> Rajasvala (a woman in menses). (66)
>
> *Samvarta Smriti*

Answer (score 5):

Yes. This thing is mentioned in Padama Puarana.

> When small hair appears (on the private parts), Soma enjoys a daughter. When she attains puberty, gandharvas (enjoy her); and when the breasts appear (prominent), Fire (enjoys her)

[Padma Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365697.html)